# What is scope in Amazon Product Advertisement API

Tags: node.js, typescript, amazon-advertising-api, amazon-product-advertising-api

I am working on Amazon advertising API. I want to get advertising reports. I am not sure about scope, how I can define scope,

```
import { HttpClient,ProfileOperation} from '@scaleleap/amazon-advertising-api-sdk'
public static async awsProductAds(store:Store) {
    console.log('testing... ads')
    try {
    const auth = {
      accessToken: store.accessToken,
      clientId: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
      scope: 10000000000 // Use your Profile ID as the value for the management scope
    }
    const httpClient = new HttpClient('https://advertising-api-eu.amazon.com', auth)
    const profileOperation = new ProfileOperation(httpClient);
    const data = profileOperation.listProfiles()
    console.log(data)
    }
    catch (e) {
      console.log('Amazon Ads Report Error : '+e)
    }
  }
```

Without scope, I am getting this error:

> UnauthorizedError: HTTP 401 Unauthorized
>
> at apiErrorFactory (E:\amazon_reportcentral\amazon_reports\node_modules@scaleleap\amazon-advertising-api-sdk\src\errors.ts:83:14)
> at HttpClient.handleApiResponse (E:\amazon_reportcentral\amazon_reports\node_modules@scaleleap\amazon-advertising-api-sdk\src\http-client.ts:82:28)
> at HttpClient.apiRequest (E:\amazon_reportcentral\amazon_reports\node_modules@scaleleap\amazon-advertising-api-sdk\src\http-client.ts:138:17)
> at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
> code: 'UNAUTHORIZED',
> requestId: 'W2TDB73G64XRN1A0DSAB'
> }

Please help how I can get amazon advertising reports with nodejs api-sdk